# Как REST запросом выгрузить с сервера несколько файлов за один раз?

Tags: http, rest

Как выгрузить один файл с сервера понятно - используем application/octet-stream.
Как загрузить несколько файлов на сервер вроде тоже понятно - используем multipart/form-data.

Comment: передавайте файлы в json в base64

Comment: К сожалению до сих пор не ничего лучше чем запаковать их в архив :(